# How to show a left colored border on each ListView row?

Tags: java, android, listview, colors, border

How to show only a left colored border on each ListView row?

I have a 5 degree termometer for user reputation and I want to show the respective colors at the left border of each listview row.

Like this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nP1CM.jpg)

Thanks guys!!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [Ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: like this [link](http://imgur.com/a/Z2u76)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to create a dummy `View` in your item layout. That way you can easily change the color of the background when you bind the layout to the data. Something like this:

item_list_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout     
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <View 
        android:id="@+id/termometherIndicator"
        android:height="match_parent" android:width="4dp"
        android:background="@color/default_color" />
    <LinearLayout ....>
        <!-- The rest of the item layout goes here -->
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then get the view reference in code behind using the `Id` and change the background color to whatever you need.

Answer (score 1):

The `ListView` row should be an horizontal `LinearLayout`, and include this at the beginning, as a first child, followed by the TextView:

```
<View
android:id="@+id/reputationColor"
android:layout_width="4dp" //Aproximately the size from your image
android:layout_height="36dp" //About the size of a List Row, but less, as seen in your image
android:layout_gravity="top"
/>
```

You will need a `CustomAdapter` for your `ListView`, which you can find a full example in [here](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView)

Inside the CustomAdapter, you can set the colour programatically with

```
View reputationColor = (View)findViewById(R.id.reputationColor); 
switch (reputation) {
case 1:
reputationColor.setBackgroundColor(#ff0000);
break; //Include other cases up to 5
default:
break;
}
```

For more information on CustomAdapters, go to the following websites:

- [ONE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getView(int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup))
- [TWO](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)
- [THREE](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a panel to the leftmost part of your app. In that panel you can place one of the predefined images of thermometer. You only have 5 levels, right? Once value changes - select corresponding image of thermometer reading and redraw gui element.